# if/else clause in seperate class to call multiple times in Fragment view

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-fragments

I have an issue with my android app.
I have an Spinner where users can choose between 20 options.
This get saved in a database.

I use "getExtras" to retrieve the String from the Spinner choice:

```
String spinner = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("spinner");
```

I also retrieve a weight from "getExtras":

```
int weight = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("weight", +0);
```

Then I use if/else to check which options were chosen:

```
option1 = (String) ("Option1");
//... all 20 strings
option20 = (String) ("Option20");

if (option1.equals(spinner)) {

    int weekint = (int) (weight * 0.420); //the 2nd parameter (0.420) is the only different between all 20 options

    String week = weekint + " g"; //i use the weekint to String
    textView1.setText(week);      //and put it in a text view
// Here is my problem. I want to add more if/else statements inside this (and all other options)
//all the if/else statements inside here use the "weekint" integer and work with it.
// It's about 200 lines codes and I can't copy it into each "main" (option) if/else statement.
// See below for more information 
// let's first end this code with 19 more else/if for all options like that
 } else if (option20.equals(spinner)) {
           int weekint = (int) (weight * 0.350);}
```

Can I export the inner if/else statments in an extra class? ( I use fragment (extends Fragment))

They look like this:

```
if (checkbox1 == 0){


    int inner1weekint = (int) (weekint * 0.8);
    String inner1week = inner1weekint + " g";
    tv23.setText(inner1wekk);

    int inner2weekint = (int) (weekint * 0.2);
    String inner2week = inner2weekint + " g";
    tv26.setText(inner2week);
//... a lot more like this
```

As you see, they all need the "weekint" int from the options if/else statement.
If I try to use a new class with only the inner if/else statements they don't have access to this "weekint".

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure weight is not `-0` ? ;)

Comment: whats the different?
I retrieve the correct value with +0

Comment: There's none; You don't have to add a sign to zero. Nevertheless, just a side node, not related to your problem.

Comment: haha ok, well if I just write '("weight")' I get an error so I added the +0 :D

Comment: This is basically a simple "extract method" refactoring. Just write a method that gets everything it needs as a parameter. Then move it to a new class. I would make that method `static` so it's more convenient to call. Such a method is also called "utility method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you export the inner if else statements into another class, the real problem is that the new class won't have access to all the variables you use in those statements, eg TextView1 won't be available to it.  You could put the calculation of weekint in another class and invoke with something like

```
int weekint = myNewClass.calculateWeekInt(spinner, weight);
```

but instead of a new class, I think you'd be better just making it a new method inside your current class.

You could also make an array out of the option strings and the weight multiples instead of doing a bunch of if statements.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I used a new method. I don't know why I wanted to use a new class^^
works great!